# css | button:hover background still grey

Tags: css, wordpress, pseudo-class

I noticed that the buttons (button.term) next to the grid turn grey when hover. I've set the pseudo classes (hover, focus, active, visited) to white!important, but it still doesn't work.

[Website](https://dercampus.ch/en/)

Comment: Generally most folks on SO won't click on random website links to find a problem like this.  You should set up a JSFiddle to recreate the problem and post it here.

Comment: Inspect and find out what is overriding the style

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question.  Also, please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the css:

`box-shadow:none;`

```
.is-desktop #course_grid button.term {
    flex-basis: 7.5%;
    color: transparent!important;
    background: no-repeat center center;
    background-color: white !important;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 0.7;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
```

This overrides your code.

Comment: thank you, but it wasn't necessary, "none" was enough

Comment: This was your original code. Just pointed out where the problem was so you could fix it yourself and learn from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code

```css
<style>
  button:hover{
  box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specific the class before if you have link this

```
.class-dvi .button:hover {background-color: white}
```

also you can use box-shadow: none; but don't think you need.

Or if you have add the class button.term you need to write `.term button:hover`

If you post the code will be more simple answer you.